# Removal of several identical elements ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have 4 `ComboBox` in each of them there are 5 elements: " ", "1", "2", "3", "4".
I have to make if the item "1" is selected in a `ComboBox`, it is automatically excluded from other .And if  the item " " is selected in the `ComboBox`insame
it is automatically returned to the other. So same need for other items except " ".
I tried to do this Here's the code:

---

```
public void vubadditems(ComboBox<String> vub1,ComboBox<String> vub2,ComboBox<String> vub3,ComboBox<String> vub4){
    vub1.getItems().addAll(" ","1","2","3","4");
    vub2.getItems().addAll(" ","1","2","3","4");
    vub3.getItems().addAll(" ","1","2","3","4");
    vub4.getItems().addAll(" ","1","2","3","4");
}
public void vubact(ComboBox<String> vub1,ComboBox<String> vub2,ComboBox<String> vub3,ComboBox<String> vub4){
    if(vub1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!=" "){    
    vub2.getItems().remove(vub1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    vub3.getItems().remove(vub1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    vub4.getItems().remove(vub1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    s=vub1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    }else{
    }
    if(vub2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!=" "){    
        vub1.getItems().remove(vub2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        vub3.getItems().remove(vub2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        vub4.getItems().remove(vub2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    if(vub3.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!=" "){    
        vub1.getItems().remove(vub3.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        vub2.getItems().remove(vub3.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        vub4.getItems().remove(vub3.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    if(vub4.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!=" "){    
        vub1.getItems().remove(vub4.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        vub2.getItems().remove(vub4.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        vub3.getItems().remove(vub4.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
}
public void vubq1ac(){
    vubact(q1vub1,q1vub2,q1vub3,q1vub4);
}
public void initialize(){
vubadditems(q1vub1,q1vub2,q1vub3,q1vub4);
    vubadditems(q2vub1,q2vub2,q2vub3,q2vub4);
    vubadditems(q3vub1,q3vub2,q3vub3,q3vub4);
    vubadditems(q4vub1,q4vub2,q4vub3,q4vub4);
    vubadditems(q5vub1,q5vub2,q5vub3,q5vub4);
}
```

---

q1vub1, q1vub2, q1vub3, q1vub4 is loaded from `FXML_file` `ComboBox`'s
I add vubq1ac as action listiner on `ComboBox`
But I have some Exception and program works incorrect
Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$177(ListViewBehavior.java:269)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:75)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:378)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1403)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:256)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:220)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: At first dont't compare `String` by `==` or `!=`, use equals instead: `vub1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals(" ")`

Comment: @MBec OK i rewrite :?         'if(vub1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals(" ")){}else{'  but the program still gives me exception

Comment: You have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` so check that your loop only Iterate over the maximum size of your lists !

Answer (score 0):

If you follow your current approach your code will be quite long and rather hard to debug. Currently it seems that:

1. You only remove and never return items.
2. You don't store the previously selected value. Imagine that in your first `ComboBox` "1" was selected (and subsequently, excluded from other components), and you decide to change it back to " ". You can't get the previous value directly from the `ComboBox`, because `.getSelectedItem()` will only return the current value, which would be " " already.

I'll present you my approach and tell you briefly how it works.

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(items, " ", "1", "2", "3", "4");

        List<ComboBox> comboBoxList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ComboBox c = new ComboBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(items));
            c.setValue(c.getItems().get(0));
            c.valueProperty().addListener(removeFromOtherCombo(comboBoxList, c));
            comboBoxList.add(c);
        }

        root.getChildren().addAll(comboBoxList);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static ChangeListener removeFromOtherCombo(List<ComboBox> boxes, ComboBox current) {
        return (o, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (newVal.equals(oldVal)) {
                return;
            } 

            if (!oldVal.equals(" ")) {
                boxes.stream()
                        .filter(c -> !c.equals(current))
                        .forEach((ComboBox) -> {
                            ComboBox.getItems().add(oldVal);
                        });
            }

            if (!newVal.equals(" ")) {
                boxes.stream()
                        .filter(c -> !c.equals(current))
                        .forEach((ComboBox) -> {
                            ComboBox.getItems().remove(newVal);
                        });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

For each `ComboBox` I create a `ChangeListener` that's aware of every other `ComboBox` and the `ComboBox` to which it's assigned.

```
c.valueProperty().addListener(removeFromOtherCombo(comboBoxList, c));
```

The `ChangeListener` is notified every time you pick a new value, and fortunately for us it receives both old and new value.

If old value is equal to new value then there's nothing for us to do.

```
if (newVal.equals(oldVal)) {
    return;
}
```

If old value is a number (e.g. we're changing from "1" to "2") then we have to return the previously selected number to every `ComboBox` except one, which was filtered.

```
if (!oldVal.equals(" ")) {
    boxes.stream()
            .filter(c -> !c.equals(current))
            .forEach((ComboBox) -> {
                ComboBox.getItems().add(oldVal);
            });
 }
```

The same approach is taken when we're changing to a number, but this time we have to remove it from every `ComboBox` except one.

Comment: I use a Scene builders and FXML files and I initializate `ComboBox` ,so can you rewrite this part of code:
`List<ComboBox> comboBoxList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ComboBox c = new ComboBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(items));
            c.setValue(c.getItems().get(0));
            c.valueProperty().addListener(removeFromOtherCombo(comboBoxList, c));
            comboBoxList.add(c);`

Comment: Then change this line `ComboBox c = new ComboBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(items));` to `ComboBox c = comboBoxList.get(i);` and add your `ComboBox` to the list before the loop starts: `comboBoxList.add(comboBox1);` etc. You can use foreach loop in that case.

Comment: OK thank you very much I rewrote their own code but I have been `exception`s because my program should automatically select one of the elements of `ComboBox` but copying your code rewrite these `exception`s, I do not appear

Comment: The initial value of a `ComboBox` is null. Because I did not want to handle it, I explicitly set the selected item to the first one, here: `c.setValue(c.getItems().get(0));`.

Comment: I use your code at the beginning  `intialize ` and then change my Selection:  
`public void initialize(){your code...   
q1vub1.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(q1cprvar1);
  q1vub2.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(q1cprvar2);
  q1vub3.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(q1cprvar3);
  q1vub4.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(q1cprvar4);`
`q1cprvar1`,`q1cprvar2` and others is `int` variables that the program reads the file at the beginning of programs.

so program change selection with `ActionListener`

Comment: But when i yse my rewriting code i had `exeptions` that disappeared when I used rewrite your code